# Button click event binding in Electron js

Tags: node.js, electron

I have started using electron js to develop desktop application.

I want to know that how to bind button click event with javascript function so that I can perform other operation.

I used below HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Manav Finance</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="getData()" value="Get Data" />
  </body>

  <script>
    // You can also require other files to run in this process
    require('./renderer.js')
  </script>
</html>
```

My renderer.js code looks like this:

```
function getData(){
        console.log('Called!!!');
    }
```

But I am getting error that:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getData is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

Updated HTML document and removed require() method and its working now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Manav Finance</title>
    <script src="renderer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="btnEd" value="Get Data" onclick="getData()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `getData` function?

Comment: @aug: Updated the Post. I am setting in renderer.js

Comment: Try moving the `script` tag above `body`. The issue right now is your script where your function is being defined is being defined after the DOM has rendered input so naturally it will not know how to bind the click event if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I try moving script tag in head section, still same error.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To explain this for future users.  `<script>` tag's in an HTML document are executed in the global scope, this means that `this === window`, I.e. any function or variable declared in the script inherently becomes global.

When you `require` a script it becomes isolated in it's own context (it is wrapped in another function so `this !== window`, I.e. any function or variable declared in the script is not available globally.

The correct way to do this is to use `require('./renderer.js')` and to use this code

```
function getData() {
    ...
}

document.querySelector('#btnEd').addEventListener('click', () => {
    getData()
})
```

Comment: how do you use the event argument in electron?

Comment: Where should one add the `require` statement to, in this example?