# Electron: How to get webContents (to check on backgroundThrottling)?

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

To check on the state of `backgroundThrottling` I want to access the `webContents` inside an event handler:

```js
window.addEventListener('blur', ()=>{
    if(window.webContents.backgroundThrottling)
        ...
});
```

But when the event occurs I get the error message: "Cannot read property 'backgroundThrottling' of undefined". I tried a few things, but I could never get a defined `webContents`.

As requested I add:
This runs in index.html, so the renderer process?
The window "was just available". I don't know where it was defined (but neither in index.html nor in renderer.js). (I'm quite new to JS and even newer to Electron.)

When I print the window in `console.log` I get:

```
global {window: global, self: global, document: ...
```

So maybe this isn't the browser window, but the Electron one? But how do I get the browser window from within index.html (not creating a new one, but getting the current one)?

EDIT: But since it has all of my document's things in it it should be the browser window, shouldn't it?

Comment: In which scope does this code run (main or renderer)? Is `window` a `BrowserWindow` or simply the `window` global inside a `BrowserWindow`'s renderer process? Please clarify by [edit]ing your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The `window` global is, for security reasons, not an Electron `BrowserWindow` but the pure `window` global you'll find inside any given (actual) browser. You'll need to execute your code on the main process.

---

`webContents` is an additional class by Electron and as such only available in the main process (see [its docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents)). Thus, the renderer process (the window you open) cannot access it.

`window.webContents` only works if `window` is a variable of the `BrowserWindow` class, this means that you need the same object you create in your main process when opening a window.

To resolve your problem, pass a message via IPC (inter-process communication) to your main process in the event listener and execute the code depending on `webContents.backgroundThrottling` inside the `ipcMain` listener. This could be done like so:

```js
// renderer process (index.html)
const { ipcRenderer } = require ("electron");

window.addEventListener ("blur", () => { ipcRenderer.send ("window-blur", null); });
```

```js
// main process (app.js or main.js or whatever you call it)
const { ipcMain } = require ("electron");

ipcMain.on ("window-blur", (event, args) => {
    // args === null, but event.sender is the webContents of the BrowserWindow
    // which sent the event
    if (event.sender.backgroundThrottling) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

However, it could be worthwhile to read up on IPC in Electron (there are more elegant ways to solve this problem, especially if you only need `webContents.backgroundThrottling` from the main process) as well as the dual-process-model (main and renderer process) as you seem to be lacking understanding of the concept which is important not only for programming in Electron, but also for the security of Electron applications.

These documentation pages could be helpful resources:

- [`ipcMain`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main), the main-process end of the IPC module
- [`ipcRenderer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer), the renderer-process end
- [`BrowserWindow`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window), the main-process object for Electron windows
- [Electron Security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security), especially [Isolation For Untrusted Content](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#isolation-for-untrusted-content) and [Security Recommendations](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#checklist-security-recommendations)
- [Electron - How to use main and renderer processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59373793) (question and useful answer here on Stack Overflow)

---

Note: Above code only works if you have `nodeIntegration` set to `true` in the `BrowserWindow`'s settings when creating it. This, however, is not in the scope of this question and has been answered countless times here on SO before.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is ok to post the final solution here, which I found thanks to the previous answer?

The task was to pause a clock if background throttling was active. Since the reaction had to happen in the renderer process, the renderer process event needed to be mirrored back from main to the renderer, but only in case background throttling was active:

```
//-------------------------------------
// renderer process (index.html):

const { ipcRenderer }   = require ("electron")
let boolClockPausing    = 0 // stores the user's setting, not the pausing because of throttling

window.addEventListener ( "blur",  ()=>{
    if(!boolClockPausing) ipcRenderer.send ("window-focus", 0) })   // tell main about blur

window.addEventListener ( "focus", ()=>{
    if(!boolClockPausing) ipcRenderer.send ("window-focus", 1) })   // tell main about focus

// main tells us our previous blur/focus event happened with bgThrottling:
ipcRenderer.on ("window-focus-throttling", (event, boolFocus)=>{
    ClockOff( boolFocus ? 0 : 1 ) })

//-------------------------------------
// main process (main.js):

const { ipcMain } = require ("electron");

ipcMain.on ("window-focus", (event, boolFocus) => {
    const webContents = event.sender
    if (webContents.backgroundThrottling)
        webContents.send ("window-focus-throttling", boolFocus)
})
```

With a working example I find it much easier to find and understand more information from the Electron documentation.